# Azure function will not create blob metadata

Tags: c#, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage

I like to write some metadata to an existing blob. The function runs without any error but the blob metadata not changes or not created.

```
 #r "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage"

 using System; using System.Configuration; using System.Net; using
 System.Text; using Microsoft.Azure; using
 Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage; using
 Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob;

 public static void Run(string myQueueItem, ILogger log) {
     string[] myQueueItems = myQueueItem.Split(':');

     string DocumentID = myQueueItems[0];
     string MetaDataKey = myQueueItems[1];
     string MetaDataValue = myQueueItems[2];


     CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse("");
     CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
     CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("test123");

     CloudBlob blob = container.GetBlobReference("teams.xlsx");
     blob.FetchAttributesAsync();

     if (blob.Metadata.ContainsKey(MetaDataKey))
     {
         blob.Metadata[MetaDataKey] = MetaDataValue;
     }
     else{
         blob.Metadata.Add(MetaDataKey, MetaDataValue);
     }

     blob.SetMetadataAsync();

     log.LogInformation($"C# Queue trigger function processed: {blob.Name}");

 }
```

Input: Test:Test:Test
Output: C# Queue trigger function processed:teams.xlsx

The functions runs but not create the metadata “Test” with the value “Test” on the blob teams.xlsx.

Regards
Stefan

Comment: I'm not familiar with this operation, but assuming `SetMetadataAsync()` is truly `async`, you are doing a fire-and-forget call because you do not `await` it. It could be that the request ends before the operation is done, causing your problem. This is horrible practice, but only to see what happens until you can implement correctly, see what happens if you change it to `blob.SetMetadataAsync().Result;`

Comment: Thanks, but. Result will not work. I will rebuild the code so I can use await. When I paste the code in a console application it will be the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you Crowcoder for your help. I Change the code and now it runs.

`await blob.SetMetadataAsync();`